# Best method for turning a bool list to a linq query against string values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a part of my application which querys a database for records.  One of the fields in this query is a string type status of known values:

Open, Closed, Cancel

The user has 3 check boxes and can select any combination to determine which types of records they get back.  So in my view model I have a status filter property with 3 bools:

```
public class SalesOrderStatusFilter
{
    public bool Open { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
}
```

Now when a query is run, I'd like to filter the results based on the chosen status types.  Right now I've got a linq query like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<SalesOrders> GetSalesOrders(SalesOrderParams parameters)
    {
        return  _dbContext.SalesOrderLookup()
            .Where(x => (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Open") && parameters.SalesOrderStatusFilter.Open)
                        || (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Closed") && parameters.SalesOrderStatusFilter.Closed)
                        || (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Cancel") && parameters.SalesOrderStatusFilter.Canceled)).ToList();
    }
```

This is a common pattern across my application and I'd like to find a better solution that I can reuse without having to keep typing out the query every time.  I've already tested out converting my db string statuses to enums using some custom attributes, reflection, etc, but I'm worried it's a bit overkill when I'm doing mostly view-only type querys for these various reports, so I'm not sure I'm going to stick with it.  It's also added a bit of a performance hit to do the enum conversion (The enum values didn't always match the database values, so thats why I was using reflection and custom attributes).

Can anybody recommend a good approach to dealing with this problem?

Edit:
for clarity, the SalesOrderStatusFilter is a property of another

```
public class SalesOrderParams
{
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public SalesOrderStatusFilter SalesOrderStatusFilter { get; set; }
}
```

I think the main challenge I'm trying to solve is mapping the bools to their string equivalents, which may not always match by name (sometimes theres a space, for example), and then making a more concise and reusable call.

Comment: Is `SalesOrderParams` your enum?

Comment: bit flags and bit masks?

Comment: And what is `EqualsTrim()`?

Comment: If you used a `[Flags]` enum, then you can use bit flags

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, I butchered my code a bit.  See the edit.  EqualsTrim is an extension method that trims whitespace and does an Equals() string compare.

Comment: You could simplify the code to `.Where(x => statusList.Contains(x.Status))` where `statusList` is an array of the values based on selected values

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this
First compare with status again compare with parameters status... (&& replace for ==)

---

```
  _dbContext.SalesOrderLookup()
            .Where(x => (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Open") == parameters.Open)
                        || (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Closed") == parameters.Closed)
                        || (x.Status.EqualsTrim("Cancel") == parameters.Canceled)).ToList();
```

Comment: OP is comparing with an `enum`, not a string!

Comment: **Please try... **
         x.Status.ToLower().Trim().Equals(parameters.ToString().ToLower().Trim())

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `bool` type? Even if you use `enums` and define it as byte type, it takes 1-byte length for each record while using 3 `bool` type, takes 3-bit length. Also the performance of checking one bit is higher than comparing a string. So I think better choice for you is defining three `bool` type for status variables as you define check boxes. Also in this way you will be able to read from and writ to db directly without any data conversion.